# Webpack copy files, filter out bundled files

Tags: webpack

I've found the CopyWebpackPlugin which does almost what I need out of the box.
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

But if I specify a folder to be copied or a pattern, is there some way I could filter out any file that webpack has bundled?
So that I'll only copy files that are not included within a bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this. My suggestion would be to add files to the CopyWebpackPlugin as you need them. I realize this means restarting the server a lot to get to the next failure and will be painful the first time. But luckily you will only have to do it once.